# How to plot a graph true value against predicted value when the size is different?

Tags: python, matplotlib, xgboost, lightgbm, xgbregressor

I am new to Python and I am currently working on a project with 16k rows of data to predict the game global sales. So I have decided to use LGB and XGB Regressor, and split my train and test dataset.

```
predictor_columns = [c for c in df3.columns if c != 'Global_Sales']

X = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns = predictor_columns)
y = df3['Global_Sales']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state= 42)

model2 = LGBMRegressor(random_state=42)

model2.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

So when I try to plot the predicted value against the true value:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(y_test, y_pred2, c='crimson')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

p1 = max(max(y_pred2), max(y_test))
p2 = min(min(y_pred2), min(y_test))
plt.plot([p1, p2], [p1, p2], 'b-')
plt.xlabel('True Values', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Predictions', fontsize=15)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The following error occurred:

```
x and y must be the same size
```

So I checked the shape of my true and predicted y and I found that:

```
y_pred2.shape
(3156,)

y_test.shape
(789,)
```

I am terribly stuck on this, please help !

Comment: Hi, do you expect that `y_pred2` and `y_test` have the same shape. If so do you mind to share how `y_pred2` is calculated?

Comment: Hi there! I managed to figure it out on my own ! I made a careless mistake of fitting it with training data , htats why they got different sizes